A combinatorial optimization problem including inverse matrix calculation
My research topic is a capacitor selection problem on a port network. Each capacitor on the load affects the input impedance $Z_{in}$ in the below constraint function. We try to ensure that the magnitude of input impedance is below a target value ($Z_{in} < Z_{target}$), while minimizing the total cost. It is an optimization problem that has complicated constraint functions.
Below is the problem formulation:
\begin{align}
&\text{Given} & &Z_{aa} \text{: a complex number} \\
& & &Z_{pa} \text{: a complex column vector, and } Z_{ap} = (Z_{pa})^T \\
& & &Z_{pp} \text{: a complex symmetric matrix (not Hermitian)} \\
& & &Z_{target} \text{: a real number} \\\\
&\text{Constraint} & &|Z_{in}| =\left| Z_{aa} - Z_{ap} \left(Z_{pp} + \color{red}{Z_{qq}} \right)^{-1} Z_{pa} \right| < Z_{target} \\\\
&\text{Variables} & &\color{red}{Z_{qq}} = \text{diag}(\color{red}{q_1, \ldots, q_p}) \text{, where $\color{red}{q_i}$ belongs to a finite set of complex numbers}
\end{align}
I found it difficult to handle these constraints that the optimization variables appear in the inverse matrix. The matrix structure is somehow symmetric and I guess some nice properties may be applied. I wish it could be simplified to at most a polynomial of optimization variables, and I have tried Schur complement and eigendecomposition, but both failed. Are there any decomposition or approximation techniques that may help simplify these constraints? I am grateful for any suggestions.
Thanks
